# Product id return empty in WC_Order - WooComerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, product

I'm using WooComerce plugin version 2.6.11 and WordPress version is 4.7.2. I'm trying to get all products with product metadata of order (order_id=273). I tried like below. but `$item['product_id']` return empty. nothing is returned.

```
    function custom_get_order_details($order_id){
      global $woocommerce; 


      // for test im using $order_id = 273
      $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );

      foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ){

          print_r($item_id);
          echo $product_id = wc_get_order_item_meta($item_id, '_product_id', true);
          echo "<br>test_30<br>";
          echo $variation_id = wc_get_order_item_meta($item_id, '_variation_id', true);
          echo $quantity = wc_get_order_item_meta($item_id, '_qty', true);

      }
      //$curl = curl_init();
      //curl post here
    }
    add_action( 'woocommerce_payment_complete', 'custom_get_order_details', 10, 1 );
```

if I print the `$item` inside for loop. it prints

```
array(4) { ["name"]=> string(4) "Test" ["type"]=> string(9) "line_item" ["item_meta"]=> NULL ["item_meta_array"]=> array(9) { [1]=> object(stdClass)#823 (2) { ["key"]=> string(4) "_qty" ["value"]=> string(1) "1" } [2]=> object(stdClass)#822 (2) { ["key"]=> string(10) "_tax_class" ["value"]=> string(0) "" } [3]=> object(stdClass)#821 (2) { ["key"]=> string(11) "_product_id" ["value"]=> string(4) "2856" } [4]=> object(stdClass)#820 (2) { ["key"]=> string(13) "_variation_id" ["value"]=> string(1) "0" } [5]=> object(stdClass)#819 (2) { ["key"]=> string(14) "_line_subtotal" ["value"]=> string(3) "100" } [6]=> object(stdClass)#818 (2) { ["key"]=> string(11) "_line_total" ["value"]=> string(3) "100" } [7]=> object(stdClass)#817 (2) { ["key"]=> string(18) "_line_subtotal_tax" ["value"]=> string(1) "0" } [8]=> object(stdClass)#816 (2) { ["key"]=> string(9) "_line_tax" ["value"]=> string(1) "0" } [9]=> object(stdClass)#815 (2) { ["key"]=> string(14) "_line_tax_data" ["value"]=> string(45) "a:2:{s:5:"total";a:0:{}s:8:"subtotal";a:0:{}}" } } }
```

it is also return empty  -- `$order->get_item_meta($item_id, '_qty', true)`

I dont know what Im wrong with this.

[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can get the order items details of order by

```
   // Getting an instance of the order object

    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    $items = $order->get_items();

   //Loop through them, you can get all the relevant data:

    foreach ( $items as $item ) {
        $product_name = $item['name'];
        $product_id = $item['product_id'];
        $product_variation_id = $item['variation_id'];
    }
```

Comment: Im not working in template files. im using this code functions.php

Comment: @Vel Please paste your snippet so I can check it?

Comment: @vel If you are getting print_r($item_id); then definitly you can get the value. There is no return statement in your snippet. you need to return whole as array or first product id only?

Comment: I have fixed these issue some other way. I asked this question 3 months before. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

> It'll be `$item_data` not `$item`, there is a typo error.

```
echo '$item["product_id"] <i>(product ID)</i>: ' . $item_data['product_id'] . '<br>'; //<--- notice $item_data
echo '$item["name"] <i>(product Name)</i>: ' . $item_data['name'] . '<br>'; //<--- notice $item_data
```

UPDATE v2

You can also get the `product_id` from `item_meta` key like this

```
foreach ($items as $item_id => $item) {
    //..
    echo $item['item_meta']['_product_id'][0];
    echo $item['item_meta']['_qty'][0];
    //...
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I update my question. No luck. i changed $item_data to $item. not working.

Comment: $item['name'] is return the product name. but product id return empty.

Comment: I have update my answer. and `product_id` key is missing in your `var_dump`, so you can get it form `item_meta`.

Comment: No luck @raunakgupta.

Comment: I have added image in my question part

Comment: can you create a fresh order and then try with the above code.